# How to get `INDEX UTF8` and `DATA UTF8` message data by using MESSAGE ID (Chrysalis Testnet - Rust)

Tags: documentation, chrysalis

I used the `message_time.rs` code from [iotaledger/iota.rs](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.rs/blob/dev/examples/message_time.rs) to send a message to the Chrysalis testnet:

```
use iota::Client;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Create a client instance
    let iota = Client::builder()
        .with_node("https://api.lb-0.testnet.chrysalis2.com")
        .unwrap()
        .finish()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let message = iota
        .message()
        .with_index("Hello")
        .with_data("Tangle".to_string().as_bytes().to_vec())
        .finish()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let message_id = message.id().0;
    println!("Message ID: {}", message_id);

    let _ = iota.retry_until_included(&message_id, None, None).await.unwrap();

    let metadata = iota.get_message().metadata(&message_id).await.unwrap();
    match metadata.referenced_by_milestone_index {
        Some(ms_index) => {
            let ms = iota.get_milestone(ms_index).await.unwrap();
            println!("Message got referenced by milestone {} at {}", ms_index, ms.timestamp);
        }
        _ => println!("Message is not referenced by a milestone"),
    }
}
```

If the message is successfully added to the testnet the code returns the `message_id`, for eg.

```
Message ID: a9c7dc2745b0c60f379be01eacbda9e8fdf2019aebaba41710ebd5315a4ecf0c
```

The data associated with the ID can be viewed via [Chrysalis Testnet Explorer](https://explorer.iota.org/chrysalis) by entering the MessageID in the search bar. An example of the data is shown in the next image.

[image]

I tried to write a program to get `INDEX UTF8` and `DATA UTF8` data from the message by using the `MESSAGE ID`, but I couldn't figure out from the [API Documentation](https://client-lib.docs.iota.org/docs/iota/index.html) which function/method to use. Can please someone help?

Answer (score 1):

`iota.get_message().metadata(&message_id)` consumes the `GET /api/v1/messages/{messageID}/metadata` endpoint, which does not provide the actual message contents. To get the message contents, you have to use the `GET /api/v1/messages/{messageID}` endpoint, provided by `iota.get_message().data(&message_id)`. Try:

```
    let msg = iota.get_message().data(&message_id).await.unwrap();
    if let Payload::Indexation(payload) = msg.payload().as_ref().unwrap() {
        println!(
            "Index: {}",
            String::from_utf8(payload.index().to_vec()).expect("Found invalid UTF-8")
        );
        println!(
            "Data: {}",
            String::from_utf8(payload.data().to_vec()).expect("Found invalid UTF-8")
        );
    }
```